# NSDate - Extracting Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

**Problem**

I have a `timestamp` that I am converting to an `NSDate`. Now I need to extract the time. I have successfully extracted the time but the only problem I have is that if the minutes are 0, it displays "0" instead of "00". So 11:00 would be shown as: "11:0". Everything else works, for example 11:30 works fine.

**Code**

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[self.program.sd intValue]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(kCFCalendarUnitHour | kCFCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSLog(@"%d:%d", hour, minute);
```

Any suggestions? What have I done wrong? Is there a better way to extract both the hour and the minute at the same time rather than what I've done above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you getting the right values back? If all you're doing is displaying the time to the user, you should use `NSDateFormatter` to create a string from the date object.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter new] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Possibilities for format strings are documented in UTS #35: Locale Data Markup Language [Appendix F: Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Saves me a lot of code. I wrote extra code but I marked the other answer as correct because it answers that specific question (just in case someone searches for this question later). Give you a 1 up though! Thanks!

Comment: +1 I gave a concrete answer, but you gave a wider solution :)

Comment: I +1'ed you @MByD, since you answered this specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify that you want to pad with zeroes:

```
NSLog(@"%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
```